# Posso criar uma nova sessão com a tag form?

Tags: php

Olá, estou tentando criar uma simulação na montagem de Site, e para isso já consegui a simulação de troca de imagens através de $_SESSION.

Criei essa $_SESSION abaixo para carregar a primeira imagem de um banner, e permitir que o usuário efetue a troca da imagem, através de um form e um arquivo de upload de imagem.

```
// Inicio da Sessão de Upload de Imagem.
if(!isset($_SESSION['banner01'])){ // Se a Session não for iniciada
    $img01 = 'img_banner/01.png'; // Carrega essa imagem já pré determinada
}else{ // Se não
if(isset($_SESSION)) { // Se a Session for iniciada
    $img01 = ''.$_SESSION['banner01'].''; // Carrega a imagem selecionada pelo usuario através do formulário de upload de imagem.
}}
```

O formulário usado é esse abaixo:

```
<form action="recebe_upload_01.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Selecione uma nova Imagem:</label><br />
<input type="file" name="img01[]" accept="image/*" ><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="img01" value="Atualizar">
</form>
```

E o arquivo de upload usado é esse abaixo:

```
<?php
@session_start(); // Inicia a session.

if(isset( $_POST['img01'] ) ){
    //INFO IMAGEM   
    $file = $_FILES['img01'];
    $numFile = count( array_filter( $file['name'] ) );
    //PASTA
    $folder = '../img_simulador';
    //REQUiSITOS
    $permite = array( 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif' );
    $maxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5;
    //MENSAGEM
    $msg = array();
    $errorMsg = array(
        1 => 'O arquivo no upload é maior que o Limite de finido em upload_maxsize',
        2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em Max_file_size',
        3 => 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente',
        4 => 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo',
    );
    if($numFile <= 0){
        echo 'Selecione uma Imagem!!';
    }else{
        for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
            $name = $file['name'][$i];
            $type = $file['type'][$i];
            $size = $file['size'][$i];
            $error = $file['error'][$i];
            $tmp = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

            $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
            $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

            //Se você quer várias mensagens não use else.
            if($error!=0){
                $msg[] = "Erro: {$errorMsg[$error]}! Nome do arquivo: {$name}.";
            }if(!in_array($type, $permite)){
                $msg[] = "Tipo do arquivo inválido! Nome do arquivo: {$name}.";
            }if($size > $maxSize){
                $msg[] = "Tamanho do arquivo muito grande! Nome do arquivo: {$name}.";
            }else{
                $destino = $folder."/".$novoNome;
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $destino)){
                    $_SESSION['banner01'] = $destino;

            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= inicial_banner.php'>
            <script language='javascript'>
            window.alert('Imagem atualizada com sucesso!');
            </script>";
            }}}}}
?>
```

A minha pergunta é se tem como eu inserir uma ou mais imagens usando uma tag form para adiciona-las. Ou seja criando talvez novas $_SESSION com os nomes de $_SESSION['banner02'], 03, 04 e assim sucessivamente, ou até mesmo com nomes aleatórios, e as imagens sendo armazenadas na pasta de "$folder = '../img_simulador';", conforme e determinado no arquivo de upload de imagem.

Essas $_SESSION teriam que ser temporárias, pois quando o usuário der um logout, ou mesmo fechar o browser elas fossem destruídas, ficando apenas a imagem já pré determinada em uma futura abertura da pagina.

Não sei se consegui me expressar de forma compreensiva o que estou precisando, mas espero que os amigos tenham entendido a minha duvida!

Ai pergunto tem como?

E como poderia ser feito?

Grande abraço à todos, e no aguardo de boas dicas.

Comment: O nome dessas imagens vão ficar armazenados onde para uma futura abertura de página?

Comment: O que eu quero é dar a oportunidade do usuário poder adicionar quantas imagens ele quiser, já que se trata de um banner de imagens. Mas como é uma simulação, essas imagens que o usuário adicionar, irão ser destruídas a cada logout ou encerramento do browser. ficando somente a imagem inicial  já pré determinada. Ou seja, essas novas imagens adicionadas pelo usuário, não existiram em uma abertura futura de página, e a pasta onde irá armazena-las (../img_simulador), esta programada para deletar todos os arquivos a cada 24Hs.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não entendi muito bem o seu objetivo final, mas em relação a `$_SESSION`, existe somente uma para cada SESSÂO. O que acontece é que vc pode destruí-la `unset ($_SESSION)` e reinicializar novamente com outros valores. Mas acho que vc não quer isso, afinal vai perder toda informação relativa à sessão. Uma solução provável seria guradar SESSÔES dentro de SESSÔES e vc pode acessá-las quando quiser. Faça assim:

```
$_SESSION["session01"]=Grave aqui o que quiser gravar, (uma array ou qualquer coisa),
$_SESSION["session02"] =Grave aqui o que quiser gravar, (Outra array ou qualquer outra coisa).
```

Quando não precisar mais de cada uma delas, simplesmente delete-as:

`unset ($_SESSION["session01"])`//Deleta informações da sessão "session01".

Assim vc grava diferents informações e destroi posteriormente  o que precisa ser destruido, e mantém a Sessão principal até o usuário fazer o logout.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: O meu objetivo, é dar a oportunidade do usuário poder adicionar quantas imagens ele quiser, já que se trata de um banner de imagens mas como é uma simulação, essas imagens que o usuário adicionar, irão ser destruídas a cada logout ou encerramento do browser. ficando somente a imagem inicial já pré determinada.

Comment: mas durante a sessão as imagens pode ser vistas no browser?

Comment: Exato, isso mesmo.

Comment: Então a solução que vc procura é essa mesma que postei. Use $_SESSION["banner01"]="path/banner01.jpg", $_SESSION["banner02"]="path/banner02.jpg". E assim por diante.. Quando não precisar mais vc poderá destruir SESSION["banner01"], mas a $_SESSION não é destruída.

Comment: Certo @zwitterion, mas não tenho ideia de como montar o código ou ate mesmo o form para que possa adicionar as novas imagens. Esse é o meu problema... O amigo tem como me mostrar como criaria o código com o form funcionando?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa página. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.multiple.php   .... acho que da para  vc criar a partir do codio. Basta lembrar que a array $_FILES pode guardar qualquer e todos o inputs de upload de uma pagina....  acho q vc esta confundindo $_SESSION e $_FILES. Files e uma array q guarda nformações sobre alquivos de upload e $_SESSION informaçõe sobre a sessao. Tenta fazer com isso... epois t mando um codigo funcional...http://www.w3bees.com/2013/02/multiple-file-upload-with-php.html